# Fast PearsonR between 1 vector and many others?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, correlation

I am searching for a more efficient way of calculating the Pearson coefficients between a static vector of length 1000 against many other vectors of identical length.

My naive approach would be a pairwise correlation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
A = np.random.rand(1,1000)
otherVectors = np.random.rand(700,1000)

for B in otherVectors:
    R,p = stats.pearsonr(A, B)
```

Just I would like to ask if there was a faster solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate them manually, all at once.

```
def pearsonr_many(x, ys):
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_means = ys.mean(axis=1)

    xm, yms = x - x_mean, ys - y_means[:, newaxis]
    r = yms @ xm / np.sqrt(xm @ xm * (yms * yms).sum(axis=1))
    r = r.clip(-1, 1)

    prob = special.betainc(
        len(x) / 2 - 1,
        0.5,
        1 / (1 + r * r / (1 - r * r))
    )

    return r, prob
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Nice speed increase also!